# Free fermion Lagrangian invariance under chiral symmetry

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, symmetry, field-theory, chirality

I want to apply this transformation to a free-fermion lagrangian:
$$ L=\bar{\psi}(\gamma^\mu{\partial_\mu \,- m)\,\psi}$$
$$ \psi ' =\psi\; e^{i \alpha \gamma_5} $$
$$ \bar{\psi}'=\bar{\psi} \;e^{-i \alpha \gamma_5}$$
The lagrangian should be invariant only if the $$ m=0$$ i don't understand why, how this transformation act on the mass term?

Comment: you are getting wrong the transformation of $\bar{\psi}$. There is a $\gamma_0$ factor which changes the sign of the $\alpha$ parameter since it anticommutes with $\gamma_5$. In the end you should get $\bar{\psi} ^\prime = \bar{\psi}e^{i\alpha\gamma_5}$. This means that the mass term goes to $m\bar{\psi} e^{2i\alpha\gamma_5}\psi$, which is not invariant if $m\neq0$

Answer (score 3):

The transformation for $\bar \psi$ is not correct.
Since $\bar \psi = \psi^{\dagger} \gamma^{0}$, and the transformation for $\psi$ is $\psi '  = e^{i\alpha\gamma^{5} } \psi$, the correct identity is
$$ \bar \psi '  = \psi ^{\dagger}   e^{-i\alpha\gamma^{5} } \gamma^{0} = \bar \psi e^{i\alpha\gamma^{5} },$$
where $\{ \gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{5} \} = 0, \, \mu = \{0 - 3\}$.
It follows that, assuming $\partial_{x}\alpha = 0$,
$$L '  =\bar{\psi}  '  (\gamma^\mu{\partial_\mu \,- m)\,\psi ' } =\bar{\psi}(\gamma^\mu{\partial_\mu \,- me^{2i\alpha\gamma^{5} })\,\psi}$$
and that
$$ L '  = L \leftrightarrow m = 0 $$